# How to build Firefox from 4.0 source and optimize it?

Tags: firefox, visual-studio-2010, compile

I have found tons of links, resources regarding this topic. However, most of them just compile it and that's it.

I want to disable debug, enable -O3 optimization (this one fails hard at the compile.. "unknown option").

Used these:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Simple_Firefox_build
http://kpangilinan.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/build-firefox-on-windows-7-with-visual-studio-2010/

**So. After I install all the stuff, how do I start the ./configure part (mozconfig?) and how do I get the -O3 flag working? (Extra part: How do I compile it for x86_64 ? I don't care about the "beta state", plugins tend to work, and the flash plugin just works fine.)**

Comment: (About the 4.0 part: The howto shows me how to check out the VERY latest source and build that. However, I want a stable, 4.0 code base if possible.)

Comment: +1 interesting, will this result in better benchmark results though?

Comment: Wow, I have got to try this when I get some time.

Comment: There's no -O3 flag in Visual Studio. Can you indicate what you really want?

Comment: @MSalters: Already solved... It was a misconception, in Visual Studio a -Ox flag exists for that purpose. And on an Intel processor you more likely want to use an Intel compiler than MinGW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How I compiled an optimized version of the latest (Nightly) Firefox:

Here is what I have done:

1. **[Check here for the source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/download_mozilla_source_code) of the stable builds.** I've took a nightly version, because that's me...
2. Installed latest DirectX SDK, the configuration part of building informs you about this for ANGLE.
3. Use `ac_add_options --enable-optimize="-Ox -GLATFys -fp:fast -arch:SSE2"`

This basically takes O2 and [adds optimization options on top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59a3b321(v=VS.80).aspx); check the Ox, GL, GA, GT, GF, Gy, Gs docs.
It also optimizes floating points and uses the SSE2 architecture, it disables `DEBUG` by default.

If you notice that one of these is wrong feel free to inform me, but this seems to work to me...

Took 1 hour to compile on my fast laptop.

[image]

### Benchmarks of latest available versions:

**Lower is better:**

[IE9 SunSpider: 591.4 ms +/- 6.2%](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9/sunspider-results.html?%7B%223d-cube%22:%5B42,41,42,29,29%5D,%223d-morph%22:%5B5,15,16,16,16%5D,%223d-raytrace%22:%5B28,17,23,18,43%5D,%22access-binary-trees%22:%5B14,14,14,14,14%5D,%22access-fannkuch%22:%5B34,37,37,26,34%5D,%22access-nbody%22:%5B36,36,26,39,41%5D,%22access-nsieve%22:%5B12,12,7,12,12%5D,%22bitops-3bit-bits-in-byte%22:%5B5,5,5,2,5%5D,%22bitops-bits-in-byte%22:%5B18,18,18,17,18%5D,%22bitops-bitwise-and%22:%5B21,21,22,23,22%5D,%22bitops-nsieve-bits%22:%5B27,28,28,27,21%5D,%22controlflow-recursive%22:%5B8,8,8,8,9%5D,%22crypto-aes%22:%5B17,17,17,17,6%5D,%22crypto-md5%22:%5B9,14,10,13,10%5D,%22crypto-sha1%22:%5B14,16,16,15,16%5D,%22date-format-tofte%22:%5B25,25,25,25,25%5D,%22date-format-xparb%22:%5B34,36,31,34,36%5D,%22math-cordic%22:%5B3,3,3,3,3%5D,%22math-partial-sums%22:%5B44,44,32,26,45%5D,%22math-spectral-norm%22:%5B16,16,16,16,16%5D,%22regexp-dna%22:%5B22,24,11,16,24%5D,%22string-base64%22:%5B20,21,21,20,20%5D,%22string-fasta%22:%5B57,40,57,42,44%5D,%22string-tagcloud%22:%5B40,50,33,44,59%5D,%22string-unpack-code%22:%5B20,22,28,24,30%5D,%22string-validate-input%22:%5B32,31,21,28,24%5D%7D)
[FF4 SunSpider: 275.1 ms +/- 3.6%](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9.1/sunspider-0.9.1/results.html?%7B%22v%22:%20%22sunspider-0.9.1%22,%20%223d-cube%22:%5B18,17,18,14,14,15,16,17,17,17%5D,%223d-morph%22:%5B7,7,8,7,7,7,7,8,7,7%5D,%223d-raytrace%22:%5B15,16,16,14,15,17,14,16,14,14%5D,%22access-binary-trees%22:%5B5,6,6,5,5,7,6,5,6,6%5D,%22access-fannkuch%22:%5B18,18,26,17,17,18,18,17,20,17%5D,%22access-nbody%22:%5B6,6,7,7,6,6,6,7,7,8%5D,%22access-nsieve%22:%5B7,7,9,9,7,8,7,8,7,9%5D,%22bitops-3bit-bits-in-byte%22:%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1%5D,%22bitops-bits-in-byte%22:%5B7,8,6,7,7,7,7,7,9,9%5D,%22bitops-bitwise-and%22:%5B2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2%5D,%22bitops-nsieve-bits%22:%5B8,6,7,7,7,6,6,6,8,7%5D,%22controlflow-recursive%22:%5B3,2,4,3,2,3,3,2,3,3%5D,%22crypto-aes%22:%5B10,13,12,9,11,11,10,10,10,10%5D,%22crypto-md5%22:%5B4,4,6,4,4,4,5,5,4,4%5D,%22crypto-sha1%22:%5B3,4,4,3,3,3,3,4,3,3%5D,%22date-format-tofte%22:%5B21,22,21,25,20,20,19,20,22,20%5D,%22date-format-xparb%22:%5B20,22,25,21,21,19,19,20,23,20%5D,%22math-cordic%22:%5B7,6,8,7,6,7,7,8,6,8%5D,%22math-partial-sums%22:%5B11,10,11,12,12,12,10,12,11,12%5D,%22math-spectral-norm%22:%5B6,5,4,5,5,7,5,5,5,5%5D,%22regexp-dna%22:%5B14,15,16,15,15,22,15,18,16,16%5D,%22string-base64%22:%5B5,4,5,5,6,6,4,5,4,5%5D,%22string-fasta%22:%5B13,11,12,11,14,18,11,11,12,13%5D,%22string-tagcloud%22:%5B26,25,25,22,25,33,22,21,22,25%5D,%22string-unpack-code%22:%5B26,26,30,24,28,30,25,29,24,25%5D,%22string-validate-input%22:%5B9,9,10,8,8,10,9,8,9,11%5D%7D) **Winner!**
[Chrome11 SunSpider: 301.2 ms +/- 4.8%](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9.1/sunspider-0.9.1/results.html?%7B%22v%22:%20%22sunspider-0.9.1%22,%20%223d-cube%22:%5B17,13,14,15,10,12,17,9,17,8%5D,%223d-morph%22:%5B17,12,13,14,12,13,12,15,14,13%5D,%223d-raytrace%22:%5B19,13,10,20,11,18,17,12,19,17%5D,%22access-binary-trees%22:%5B3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2%5D,%22access-fannkuch%22:%5B33,21,23,25,22,22,25,28,28,25%5D,%22access-nbody%22:%5B13,8,9,8,7,8,7,8,8,8%5D,%22access-nsieve%22:%5B3,3,7,8,8,3,3,7,7,3%5D,%22bitops-3bit-bits-in-byte%22:%5B3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3%5D,%22bitops-bits-in-byte%22:%5B7,7,7,6,7,9,7,8,7,7%5D,%22bitops-bitwise-and%22:%5B10,11,11,10,10,11,11,10,12,10%5D,%22bitops-nsieve-bits%22:%5B8,18,9,8,8,9,9,8,9,9%5D,%22controlflow-recursive%22:%5B4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,4%5D,%22crypto-aes%22:%5B9,11,9,12,9,9,10,9,12,9%5D,%22crypto-md5%22:%5B8,9,6,8,6,6,5,6,8,6%5D,%22crypto-sha1%22:%5B9,9,8,13,8,9,9,9,13,8%5D,%22date-format-tofte%22:%5B14,15,15,18,11,14,13,13,17,12%5D,%22date-format-xparb%22:%5B16,16,15,24,16,16,15,15,24,14%5D,%22math-cordic%22:%5B4,4,4,6,5,4,4,4,10,4%5D,%22math-partial-sums%22:%5B15,15,15,20,16,15,14,16,20,15%5D,%22math-spectral-norm%22:%5B8,3,3,5,3,3,3,3,3,3%5D,%22regexp-dna%22:%5B11,17,11,13,10,13,13,12,11,11%5D,%22string-base64%22:%5B5,5,6,6,5,6,8,6,6,5%5D,%22string-fasta%22:%5B15,16,17,17,16,15,16,16,14,15%5D,%22string-tagcloud%22:%5B21,22,23,20,21,20,21,24,20,22%5D,%22string-unpack-code%22:%5B32,29,29,28,29,30,33,29,29,33%5D,%22string-validate-input%22:%5B14,16,14,16,14,16,17,16,16,15%5D%7D)

[IE9 Kraken: 16093.0ms +/- 0.7%](http://krakenbenchmark.mozilla.org/kraken-1.0/results.html?%7B%22v%22:%20%22kraken-1.0%22,%20%22ai-astar%22:%5B1201,1148,1152,1144,1141,1187,1148,1143,1156,1171%5D,%22audio-beat-detection%22:%5B1488,1472,1477,1407,1410,1451,1443,1409,1448,1460%5D,%22audio-dft%22:%5B2745,2435,2500,2468,2440,2427,2473,2466,2447,2431%5D,%22audio-fft%22:%5B1487,1642,1651,1702,1695,1666,1631,1616,1606,1646%5D,%22audio-oscillator%22:%5B862,1018,997,937,949,925,998,989,925,951%5D,%22imaging-gaussian-blur%22:%5B3692,3470,3449,3443,3442,3424,3344,3398,3450,3348%5D,%22imaging-darkroom%22:%5B1146,1057,1079,1091,1058,1123,1149,1155,1084,1152%5D,%22imaging-desaturate%22:%5B1268,1305,1273,1221,1322,1264,1207,1241,1278,1217%5D,%22json-parse-financial%22:%5B120,132,122,128,136,129,119,128,117,124%5D,%22json-stringify-tinderbox%22:%5B144,169,161,166,147,143,148,148,144,148%5D,%22stanford-crypto-aes%22:%5B437,443,407,416,447,445,453,455,410,431%5D,%22stanford-crypto-ccm%22:%5B346,337,368,355,352,336,331,329,369,364%5D,%22stanford-crypto-pbkdf2%22:%5B1193,1240,1136,1161,1094,1214,1206,1162,1168,1155%5D,%22stanford-crypto-sha256-iterative%22:%5B350,371,399,358,341,380,340,388,339,400%5D%7D)
[FF4 Kraken: 6446.9ms +/- 0.7%](http://krakenbenchmark.mozilla.org/kraken-1.0/results.html?%7B%22v%22:%20%22kraken-1.0%22,%20%22ai-astar%22:%5B1286,1275,1274,1284,1249,1315,1243,1286,1320,1247%5D,%22audio-beat-detection%22:%5B670,628,651,655,631,640,809,750,744,706%5D,%22audio-dft%22:%5B373,368,374,359,383,371,426,349,374,353%5D,%22audio-fft%22:%5B614,587,583,528,548,533,546,518,545,500%5D,%22audio-oscillator%22:%5B513,501,553,520,515,546,521,513,524,584%5D,%22imaging-gaussian-blur%22:%5B750,759,751,797,778,791,747,807,772,797%5D,%22imaging-darkroom%22:%5B268,270,267,259,324,278,275,263,260,263%5D,%22imaging-desaturate%22:%5B845,846,901,803,869,813,864,814,887,823%5D,%22json-parse-financial%22:%5B177,175,170,166,193,165,188,168,177,174%5D,%22json-stringify-tinderbox%22:%5B92,107,86,90,85,84,85,92,85,95%5D,%22stanford-crypto-aes%22:%5B209,246,204,268,217,294,206,223,236,201%5D,%22stanford-crypto-ccm%22:%5B172,177,164,164,156,162,154,164,155,220%5D,%22stanford-crypto-pbkdf2%22:%5B344,301,310,334,328,324,294,313,365,330%5D,%22stanford-crypto-sha256-iterative%22:%5B142,158,134,157,151,142,143,135,153,139%5D%7D) **Winner!**
[Chrome11 Kraken: 7947.7ms +/- 0.5%](http://krakenbenchmark.mozilla.org/kraken-1.0/results.html?%7B%22v%22:%20%22kraken-1.0%22,%20%22ai-astar%22:%5B274,264,251,252,251,264,254,262,257,254%5D,%22audio-beat-detection%22:%5B1761,1825,1782,1792,1777,1745,1783,1763,1765,1799%5D,%22audio-dft%22:%5B731,681,728,744,699,746,694,713,744,744%5D,%22audio-fft%22:%5B1747,1799,1756,1697,1754,1742,1767,1788,1677,1707%5D,%22audio-oscillator%22:%5B265,269,289,340,253,299,272,257,281,299%5D,%22imaging-gaussian-blur%22:%5B485,454,436,435,428,423,458,446,423,447%5D,%22imaging-darkroom%22:%5B587,584,612,611,607,600,595,617,577,601%5D,%22imaging-desaturate%22:%5B875,927,966,935,862,951,871,943,942,967%5D,%22json-parse-financial%22:%5B265,240,236,246,231,238,296,237,261,238%5D,%22json-stringify-tinderbox%22:%5B133,117,119,120,125,113,124,125,122,115%5D,%22stanford-crypto-aes%22:%5B248,216,206,211,215,211,225,223,221,221%5D,%22stanford-crypto-ccm%22:%5B200,181,223,185,194,197,183,221,201,229%5D,%22stanford-crypto-pbkdf2%22:%5B248,244,239,236,241,245,234,244,249,234%5D,%22stanford-crypto-sha256-iterative%22:%5B195,121,119,257,237,126,122,122,205,125%5D%7D)
<sub>Please note that previous test is written by Mozilla and might test Firefox specific advantages.</sub>

**Higher is better:**

IE9 V8: 2232 (R: 2097, DB: 2200, C: 3579, RT: 1697, EB: 3336, RE: 1750, S: 1687)
FF4 V8: 3716 (R: 5066, DB: 4760, C: 5318, RT: 3552, EB: 3887, RE: 1244, S: 4441)
Chrome11 V8: 7451 (R: 9976, HM: 13468, C: 11850, RT: 8304, EB: 17153, RE: 2076 S: 2714) **Winner!**
<sub>Please note that previous test is written by Google and might test Chrome specific advantages.</sub>

[IE9 Peacekeeper: 5135

FF4 Peacekeeper: 4465](http://clients.futuremark.com/peacekeeper/results.action?key=5dhG)
[Chrome11 Peacekeeper: 8099](http://clients.futuremark.com/peacekeeper/results.action?key=5dhy) **Winner!**

**Conclusion:**

I'm currently running IE9 so it seems worthwhile to switch to Firefox.

As it is interesting that Chrome outperforms in the later tests, I might try to build an optimized Chrome later.
I'll benchmark the normal Firefox and an optimized Chrome later...

**Versions used:**

Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 RTM.
FF Minefield 4.2a1pre (2011-03-25) with `-Ox -GLATFys -fp:fast -arch:SSE2`.
Google Chrome 11.0.696.14 dev without optimization.